# Log viewer in a desktop application?

Tags: desktop-application, status, alternatives, logging

I'm developing a desktop application for analyzing source code. It basically analyzes all files in given directory and produces a text file with report.

Status of analysis is displayed in a text box with log:

[image]

Is displaying a log a good choice from UX perspective?

If not, what are other alternatives for informing user about current application status?

Answer (score 4):

**TRACE < DEBUG < INFO < WARN < ERROR < FATAL**

Logs has its own standard and i am favor of using the same standards. For a user, logs is not really a need but for a developer it is a must. If your first user will not need a log area you can make it **hidden/shown with a toggle button**.

If your log has various division like above you can also try to **differentiate and filter** with interface mechanisms. Checkbox and dropdown can be used for filtering and color codes for each state can be embedded as label.

If the process that you are doing with this program, can create big problems? **You shall also have a pop up for human confirmation**...

Good luck with your program!

Comment: +1 - make extensive use of the proper log calls and allow your users to filter by them.

Answer (score 2):

think overall the experience could be improved by making it easier for the user to skim through the log instead of reading it.

adding some kind of visual differentiation on various statuses or actions
with colors or icons for different statuses

event logs from some games and notifications on social apps or websites seem to be much more user friendly